# Not able to load images in Listview using Lrucache

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, bitmap

am using one Image view and 2 textview in listview and loading images from Web-services , but when i scroll my listview images get shuffle so i used LRUcache. Now am getting error when am using `Bitmap bitmap = mMemoryCache.get(hmList.get("StudentPhoto"))` and am getting error log

```
06-20 15:54:01.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 15:54:01.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6795): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 15:54:01.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6795):     at **X.Y.Z.adapters.A_Adapter.getView(A_adapter.java:165)**
06-20 15:54:01.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6795):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2207)
06-20 15:54:01.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6795):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
```

Reference am taking from 
[[ListView - Images shuffle while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762817/listview-images-shuffle-while-scrolling])

Comment: Did you debug what is null? cache or list or its key's value?

Comment: am passing the URL in mMemoryCache.get(), it says String Key.. am confused what i need to pass there

Comment: any String key for which hmList conains value.

Comment: no there is no key for photoURL

Comment: hmList is hashmap? Show code.

Comment: HashMap<String, Object> hmList;
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

Comment: So you must store Object against a String. You are retrieving it using `StudentPhoto`. Keep that same string in HashMap while saving that image. So your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Taking reference of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762817/listview-images-shuffle-while-scrolling

Comment: That's a list, and yours is hashmap. You should put image object like `hmList.put("StudentPhoto",imageObj);` and then retrieve it as you are doing.

Comment: map.put("StudentPhoto",js0.getString("StudentPhoto");
i have already done that in activity class and now i want to populate List with ListAapter.

Comment: everything else works fine like textview etc